# Do I need to check if directory/file exist or not?

Tags: c#, file, directory

Which one code is better?

**Code1:**

```
if (!Directory.Exists("DirectoryPathHere"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory("DirectoryPathHere");
```

**Code2:**

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("DirectoryPathHere");
```

I think **Code2** because as I saw it not gives any error and its not making new folder when the folder already exists, so I though that checking for folder existence is useless. Right?

Comment: Your first port of call for questions like this is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory.aspx).  In this case, a two-second google search for `Directory.CreateDirectory` would lead you to the correct answer.

Comment: @paddy I know already what MSDN said (I figured it out myself) but people still checks for folder existence so I wanted to know why?

Comment: Although, defensive programming such as this is never a bad idea. So I would go with version 1 personally.

Comment: Yes Code2 is also correct. CreateDirectory itself checks the directory existance.if not it will create. and i also agree with @SimonWhitehead.

Comment: @xoemab sometimes you wanna warn your user that this folder exists, so that they don't override their current folders mistakenly, perhaps this is one reason and another is that some people are over-obsessive about errors so they do unwarranted checks anywhere :) (I'm a psychologist too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to check if the directory already exists, the method does it for you. If you check on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) :

> Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they
>   already exist or unless some part of path is invalid. The path
>   parameter specifies a directory path, not a file path. If the
>   directory already exists, this method does not create a new directory,
>   but it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing directory.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a DirectoryInfo class, check if it exists, and maybe also if it does exist, check the permissions on the directory in case my current run-time permissions are not sufficient to access the contents or update the directory.
You should apply exception handling to whichever method you go with; what if, for instance, a file exists with the name of the directory?

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is the `CreateDirectory` method **implicitly** checks if the Directory Exists before attempting to create it.

For code readability it is better to use the **explicit** method `Directory.Exists` first.

I also strongly agree with @SimonWhitehead on the defensive programming front. Showing you're aware of the pit falls... and defending actively against them explicitly it in your code is a good thing:)

```
I think we can all see the fact that the second method does the same, 
but, is it cheaper in terms of being more readable? No.
```

Anyone who knows the framework will probably disagree, and I can too. But:

> Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a
>   violent psychopath who knows where you live.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html

**Edit 2:** I have a funny feeling that the compiler does this. The assembly programmers would be able to detect it before producing the IL..

Comment: I don't see how adding the check is defensive programming, because there's no possible situation where it would do anything.. Why not get even more defensive and add a few more redundant checks? `if (!Directory.Exists("DirectoryPathHere") && !Directory.Exists("DirectoryPathHere") && !Directory.Exists("DirectoryPathHere")) {` !

Comment: I do agree that it makes it clearer, but I think a comment would suffice.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I use TFS and rarely use comments, because all tasks are associated with the changesets. The readability and maintenance on the explicit code was my main point. +1 it for a tantalizing question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        // Specify the directory you want to manipulate. 
        string path = @"c:\MyDir";

        try 
        {
            // Determine whether the directory exists. 
            if (Directory.Exists(path)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
                return;
            }

            // Try to create the directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully at {0}.", Directory.GetCreationTime(path));

            // Delete the directory.
            di.Delete();
            Console.WriteLine("The directory was deleted successfully.");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        } 
        finally {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check it, but because there are many problems that occur when handling files and folder, its better that include a `try-catch` statement so that any potential problems be handled:

```
try {
   Directory.CreateDirectory("DirectoryPathHere");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error: "+ex.Message);
}
```

you could also add `finally` if its needed.